# Python - TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, flask, typeerror

```
@app.route("/data/<dataType>", methods=['GET'])
def realtime(dataType):
    _data = None
    with open(os.path.join("data/"+ dataType +".json")) as f:
    _data = json.loads(f)
return dumps(_data)
```

I wrote this code to get data in JSON format from a file, but it keeps giving me the **error:**

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

What is wrong with it?

Comment: `loads` expects a string with json, not a file object. Use `load` instead

Comment: Additionally, your indenting is very incorrect in the posted code.

Comment: yeah, it was only on the stack, i made some indent while uploading the question.    my original code is ok .  thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

**f** is a file, while [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) expects a string.  Use **f.read()** to read a string from the file.

Comment: To clarify, `f.read()` [reads the entire file as a string](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). So Stephen probably wants `json.loads(f.read())`.

Comment: Be sure to ... Oh, he's gone.